# Button in html trigger a shortcut-key

Tags: javascript, html, button, alt, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a windows application running which takes screenshot when I press "ALT+Z". I want to trigger the same action in HTML/JS; that is the HTML/JS should simulate/trigger a "ALT+Z" so that the windows application takes a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native javascript, or you can just jQuery.

Here is the one with jQuery

```
$(document).keypress("z",function(e) {
  if(e.altKey)
    alert("Alt+Z is pressed");
});
```